# reset variable after ajax call is done

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

i am calling a ajax function to check if the inputted data 
already exists in the database.
my ajax code is like this.

```
 $(document).on('change','.lawregno',function(){
                /// Your validation logic
                var regno = $(this).val();
                if(regno)
                {
                    var data = 'regno='+ regno; // this where i add multiple data using  ' & '
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        url: "{{ URL::to('admin/check_regno_exit') }}",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if(response=="1")
                            {
                                alert('LawRegNo Already Exists');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }                
            });
```

how should i make the data reset after alert message is shown.

Comment: What data are you trying to "reset"?  What do you mean by "resetting" it?

Comment: data varaible in ajax code

Comment: You can set the variable to whatever value you want.  It doesn't seem like it would matter in this example though, since that variable falls out of scope and no longer exists anyway.  It's really not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I think he wants to change the input's value to null once the ajax is done. In that case, you can save the `this` scope in another variable called `self` before the ajax call, and inside the ajax call do `$(self).val('')`.

Comment: i want to set $(this).val() to null after ajax call is made

Answer (score 0):

you can do it inside the success handler . First you have to set a variable with the reference of `$(this)` like below

```
var elm = $(this);
```

Then you can refer it in the success callback.

```
success: function (response) {
                            if(response=="1")
                            {
                                alert('LawRegNo Already Exists');
                                elm.val('');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above:

> i want to set $(this).val() to null after ajax call is made

First, capture a reference to `this` since it will no longer be in the same scope.  Any variable will do:

```
var data = 'regno='+ regno;
var element = this;
$.ajax({
    //...
});
```

Then you can use that `element` variable in your callback function to set the value of that element:

```
success: function (response) {
    if(response=="1")
    {
        alert('LawRegNo Already Exists');
        $(element).val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the same can be done with referring the jquery wrapped `$(this)` as a variable.

Comment: @Niladri: Yes, one can set a variable to any value one chooses.

Comment: @David its not working, i want to clear the textbox after alert msg is closed.

Comment: @Deb: Show your updated code in the question.  In what way is it failing?  This example will "clear the textbox" based on our understanding of the code you're using.

Comment: @Deb: Take another look at the answers posted.  Your updated code did not do what was suggested.  You need to capture a reference to the *element*, not the *value*.  The value alone can't be used to reference the element.